# Can "father" be "the father" and "mother" be "the mother"?

Tags: usage, definite-article, nouns, proper-nouns

The original sentence:

> With **mother** earning and his older children drawing substantial
>   wages **father** is seldom the dominant figure that he still was at
>   the beginning of the century.

Is it also fine to say:

> With **the mother** earning and his older children drawing substantial
>   wages **the father** is seldom the dominant figure that he still was
>   at the beginning of the century.

***?***

Are "father" and "mother" used as uncountable nouns?

Comment: "father" and "mother" in the first sentence are used as proper nouns, not uncountable nouns. And they should be stated with a capital first letter (i.e, **Father** / **Mother**). [This Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/e/capitalizing-family/) addresses this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. Using the article **the** in this sentence definitely makes it grammatically better than the original.

Comment: It's a bit late, but for anyone coming across this answer (since it is marked as the accepted one), this is actually *not* correct.  "Father"/"Mother" do not have the same meaning as "the father"/"the mother".  The comment above by @TasneemZH actually has the correct answer.